# Why Xcode / Swift does not show values during debugging?

Tags: swift, vapor

Maybe this is because a Vapor code is debugged, but I do not see the value of variables, why?

```swift
    func migrateRecipients(_ req: Request) async throws -> HTTPStatus {
        let os = try await Organization.query(on: req.db).all()
        for o in os {
            for kv in o.events {
                var pr = kv.value
                if let pricingOptions = pr.pricingOptions {
                    for (k1, pricingOption) in pricingOptions {
                        var pricingOption = pricingOption
                        for (k2, invoiceItem) in pricingOption.invoiceItems ?? [:] {
                            var invoiceItem = invoiceItem
                            invoiceItem.paymentAndInvoiceRecipientId = "me"
                            pricingOption.invoiceItems?[k2] = invoiceItem
                        }
                        pr.pricingOptions?[k1] = pricingOption
                    }

                    o.events[kv.key] = pr
                }
            }
            try await o.save(on: req.db)
        }
        return HTTPStatus.notImplemented
    }
```

[image]

Anyway changes are executed, saved in database.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my experience, Xcode quite often fails at this when using async/await.